# PHP Timer in database

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if there was an easy way of making a timer in a database with PHP , I want to make it so after 30 minutes of the row in the database being created, it gets deleted. Im sorry if this isnt specific enough but I cant see how I could put any more detail in this, feel free to comment so I can elaborate in any means necessary

Comment: You would need to run a cron task to achieve that.

Comment: Have you had a look at the mySQL trigger and event options (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html)?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [MySQL Events](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html) if you're on MySQL 5.1.6 or later.

Something along the lines of

```sql
CREATE EVENT purge_old_records
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
DO
   DELETE FROM table1 WHERE created_at <= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE;
```

should do it.

Make sure that the event scheduler is enabled by using `SHOW PROCESSLIST`. If it's ON you should see a process "`Daemon`" by user "`event_scheduler`".
Use `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`to enable the scheduler if it's currently disabled.
More on configuring the event scheduler read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-configuration.html).